# How to code morse to latin alphabet translator in C

Tags: c

So, my homework is to do morse-latin alphabet translator. So far, I've managed to code morse to latin translator, but I can't manage to get it to work other way round. 
Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(){
    int i, j;
    char alfabet[26]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char* morse[27]={".-", "-..", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
    char tekst[MAX];
    printf("Podaj tekst pisany wielkimi literami: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]c", tekst);
    for(i=0;i<27;i++){
        for(j=0;j<30;j++){
            if(tekst[i]==alfabet[j]){
            printf("%s ", morse[j]);
            }


        }

    }

}
```

NOTE: I'm at very basic level of C programming. I'm aware this could possibly be the worst method to achieve wanted result and the code itself is far from being pretty or effective, especially the for loops. This is not my worry at the moment, I'll work on it later.

So far, my biggest problem is quite petty; the program stops right after the loop finishes its last iteration. Nothing can be printed, no command will take place. I have no idea why. 
When it's fixed, my biggest problem will be the translation itself. How do I scan a morse code string (for example "- . -..- -", which translates to "TEXT") and put it into an array? I suppose I can't use the tekst[MAX] array as I did for multiple characters?

NOTE2: although any idea is going to be helpful, not all of them I'll be able to understand or implement, due to how little I know about C in general. Thank you in advance

Comment: `printf` does usually not print unless there is a `\n` character, try adding that to the end of your program.

Comment: What is the `c` in `"%[^\n]c"` for? And note that `for(j=0;j<30;j++)` will break the array `char alfabet[26]` and so it should be `for(j=0;j<26;j++)`

Comment: No idea, just found it as a way to scan until enter, deleted the "c" and the program works the same. Is it important not to include it? And thank you, changing the for loop to j<26 does make the program run after last iteration.

Comment: Note: the code for B should be `-...` , not `-..`(which is D)

Comment: As for the question about translating from Morse Code, you can use a similar code, but use `strcmp` to compare the code with the table.

Comment: Doesn't ````strcmp```` compare lenght of two strings? I can't see how I could use that, do you have any additional clues as to what I could use it for (and how)?

Comment: `strcmp` does what the man page says it does... if the two string are unequal length it won't report them as "equal". The clue was to use a similar loop but instead of comparing each input letter with a letter from one array, compare each input group wiht a string in the other array. Use `strtok` to break the input message into groups.

Comment: That seems like an idea I could try to focus on. I'll get to it later as I've got no time now and report back. Thanks for help.
But also, as I was playing with the code just now, I can't seem to get the ````scanf```` to work, so the question how to scan multiple strings separated by space remains.

Comment: You have `alfabet[26]` and `char *morse[27]`; there cannot be a homomorphism between differently sized objects. What is up with this?

Comment: that was a typo, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1000

int main(){
    int i, j;
    char alfabet[26]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    char* morse[27]={".-", "-..", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."};
    char tekst[MAX];

    printf("Podaj tekst pisany wielkimi literami: ");
    scanf("%s", &tekst);

    int length = (unsigned)strlen(tekst);

    for(i=0; i<length; i++){
        for(j=0; j<26; j++){
            if(tekst[i]==alfabet[j]){
                printf("%s ", morse[j]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Get the word entered as a string for that you need to have the string.h library. Hope you got the answer.